# Assign strings from a key value in a JSON file to other keys in the file using jq

Tags: json, jq

The goal is to, within a JSON file and using jq, assign portions of `hrefFull` to `hrefSimple` and `hrefSubsite`. There may be better ways to achieve this, but I have approached this by looking for a solution that removes everything up until the string `articles` in a key's value but preserves the string. As a result, multiple objects like the example objects below are contained in a single JSON file formatted with a `[` at the start and and `]` at the end.

Desired results:

- `hrefFull` does not change. Strings extracted from `hrefFull` are applied to `hrefSimple` and `hrefSubsite`.
- `hrefSimple` is everything after and including `articles`. If `articles` is not in the string, `hrefSimple` is the string after the final `/`. See example object 7.
- `hrefSubsite` is the string between `https://docs.mysite.com/` and `/articles...`.

Example results - object 1:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-a/articles/page-a.html",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/page-a.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-a"
}
```

Example results - object 2:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-b/articles/guide-b/page-b.html",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-b/page-b.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-b"
}
```

Example results - object 3:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-c/articles/guide-c/section-c/page-c.html",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-c/section-c/page-c.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-c"
}
```

Example results - object 4:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-d/sub-product-d/articles/page-d.html",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/page-d.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-d/sub-product-d"
}
```

Example results - object 5:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-e/sub-product-e/articles/guide-e/page-e.html",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-e/page-e.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-e/sub-product-e"
}
```

Example results - object 6:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-f/sub-product-f/articles/guide-f/section-f/page-f.html",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-f/section-f/page-f.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-f/sub-product-f"
}
```

Example results - object 7:

```
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-g/index.html",
  "hrefSimple": "index.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-g"
}
```

Failed attempt (in a Bash script):

```
siteUrl="docs.mysite.com"
jq '
(.hrefSimple = .hrefFull)
| .hrefSimple |= (gsub("https://\($siteUrl)/.*?/"; ""))
| (.hrefSubsite = .hrefFull)
| .hrefSubsite |= (gsub("https://\($siteUrl)/"; ""))
' file-1.json > file-2.json
```

The script produces both accurate and inaccurate results.

Accurate results:

- Object 1
- Object 2
- Object 3
- Object 7

Inaccurate results:

- Object 4:

  - `hrefSimple` is incorrectly `sub-product-d/articles/page-d.html` instead of `articles/page-d.html`
  - `hrefSubsite` is incorrectly `sub-product-d` instead of `product-d/sub-product-d`
- Object 5:

  - `hrefSimple` is incorrectly `sub-product-e/articles/guide-e/page-e.html` instead of `articles/guide-e/page-e.html`
  - `hrefSubsite` is incorrectly `sub-product-e` instead of `product-e/sub-product-e`
- Object 6:

  - `hrefSimple` is incorrectly `sub-product-f/articles/guide-f/section-f/page-f.html` instead of `articles/guide-f/section-f/page-f.html`
  - `hrefSubsite` is incorrectly `sub-product-f` instead of `product-f/sub-product-f`

Other unsuccessful attempts (I can provide exact results if that's helpful):

- Various iterations of `articles` in  forms of `.hrefSimple |= (gsub("https://\($siteUrl)/.*?/"; ""))` and `.hrefSubsite |= (gsub("https://\($siteUrl)/"; ""))`
- Various iterations of `.hrefSimple |= split("articles")[0]` (also within `.hrefSubsite`)

For context, if it matters, `hrefFull` comes from an Azure App Insights export of page views for a documentation website. The exported data is used in an analytics report. I am creating `hrefSimple` to join two tables and would like to filter on `hrefSubsite`. The paths in `hrefFull` are produced when generating a website using the DocFx static site generator and deploying to an Azure Blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `capture` with a regex:

```bash
. + (.hrefFull | capture(
  "^https://docs.mysite.com/(?<hrefSubsite>.*?)/(?<hrefSimple>articles.*|[^/]*)$"
))
```

```json
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-a/articles/page-a.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-a",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/page-a.html"
}
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-b/articles/guide-b/page-b.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-b",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-b/page-b.html"
}
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-c/articles/guide-c/section-c/page-c.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-c",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-c/section-c/page-c.html"
}
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-d/sub-product-d/articles/page-d.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-d/sub-product-d",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/page-d.html"
}
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-e/sub-product-e/articles/guide-e/page-e.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-e/sub-product-e",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-e/page-e.html"
}
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-f/sub-product-f/articles/guide-f/section-f/page-f.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-f/sub-product-f",
  "hrefSimple": "articles/guide-f/section-f/page-f.html"
}
{
  "hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-g/index.html",
  "hrefSubsite": "product-g",
  "hrefSimple": "index.html"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-20XSkQruBq)

If your input objects live in an array, wrap this filter into a `map(…)`.

Comment: Thank you. This solution was successful. I recognize this is out of the scope of my question, but is there a solution based on your answer if the URL does not include `articles`, but rather `restapi` or `api`? For example, what is produced now for `"hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-h/restapi/section-h/page-h.html"` is `"hrefSubsite": "product-h/restapi/section-h"` when instead I would like to produce solely `"hrefSubsite": "product-h"` in such an instance. I recognize this use case was not included in my original question, and I have still found successes with your answer.

Comment: ...and in the instance of `"hrefFull": "https://docs.mysite.com/product-h/sub-product-h/restapi/section-h/page-h.html"`.

Comment: @hcdocs Doesn't parametrizing the parts, e.g. `jq --arg host 'docs.mysite.com' --arg item 'restapi' '. + (.hrefFull | capture("^https://\($host)/(?<hrefSubsite>.*?)/(?<hrefSimple>\($item).*|[^/]*)$"))'` do what you want?